# Average value of $x\sin(x)$ from $0$ to $\infty$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, average

Are there any arguments I could use to tell that the average value of $x\sin(x)$ is zero? The average value oscillates around zero with the increasing amplitude as $x$ goes to infinite.

Comment: In what sense "average"? For example, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi n} \int_0^{2 \pi n} x \sin(x) \ \mathrm{d}x = -1$, while the limit is $1$ when taken over $(2n+1)\pi$.

Comment: The average is not $0$, it is undefined.

Comment: With average I mean (as you said) $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{l}\int\limits_0^l x\sin(x)\;dx$. My question is that if there is any reasonabe argument to tell that this is zero.

Comment: IMO, the argument that holds is "I strongly want it to be zero".

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that for $t>0$ the (integral) mean value of $x\sin(x)$ over $[0,t]$ is, by definition, equal to
$$\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t x\sin(x)\,dx=-\cos(t)+\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t \cos(x)\,dx=-\cos(t)+\frac{\sin(t)}{t}$$
which has no limit as $t$ goes to $+\infty$.
If you take the average for interval of length $t_n=\pi n+\frac{\pi}{2}$ then
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{t_n}\int_0^{t_n} x\sin(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(-\cos(t_n)+\frac{\sin(t_n)}{t_n}\right)=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(0+\frac{(-1)^n}{t_n}\right)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$A_N=\int_0^N x\sin(x)dx$$
$$ = -x\cos(x)|_{0}^N + \int_0^N\cos(x)dx$$
$$=-N\cos(N)-\sin(N)$$
Thus, $\langle x\sin(x) \rangle= \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{A_N}{N}  =  \lim_{N\to\infty} -\cos N$

Which is not defined

Comment: What is the meaning of the angle brackets around the limit ? And how is this "thing" zero ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust the angle thing means the average value. I’ve  edited my answer to explain my logic

Comment: How do you take the average value of a constant ? (Which by the way is undefined.) There is no rigor in this answer.